# grouping and summing values in a df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df

```
    typeItem    store   region      amountItems
0   Drink       Toncat  Colorado    100
1   Food        Toncat  Colorado    100
2   Toy         Toncat  Colorado    100
3   Cloth       Toncat  Colorado    100
4   Car         Bent    Mount       10
5   Moto        Bent    Mount       10
6   Bike        Timo    Mount       5
7   Fork        Logo    Iggo        50
```

1 region has many stores, and the amountItems value is already agregatted for each store,I'm trying to group and sum the amount of items per region considering only store

the output should be this:

```
    typeItem    store   region      amountItems amountItemsRegion
0   Drink       Toncat  Colorado    100         100
1   Food        Toncat  Colorado    100         100
2   Toy         Toncat  Colorado    100         100 
3   Cloth       Toncat  Colorado    100         100
4   Car         Bent    Mount       10          15
5   Moto        Bent    Mount       10          15
6   Bike        Timo    Mount       5           15
7   Fork        Logo    Iggo        50          50
```

As can be seen above, the Region: "Colorado" has many items(rows in the df), but only one store, so, there is nothing to sum, only group
Different than the Region:"Mount", which has 2 stores(but one appears twice), so I need to group them and sum(10+5)

Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `drop_duplicates` then `groupby` assign it back

```
df['new'] = df.drop_duplicates(['region','store']).groupby('region')['amountItems'].sum().reindex(df['region']).values
df
Out[1046]: 
  typeItem   store    region  amountItems  new
0    Drink  Toncat  Colorado          100  100
1     Food  Toncat  Colorado          100  100
2      Toy  Toncat  Colorado          100  100
3    Cloth  Toncat  Colorado          100  100
4      Car    Bent     Mount           10   15
5     Moto    Bent     Mount           10   15
6     Bike    Timo     Mount            5   15
7     Fork    Logo      Iggo           50   50
```